# Cross match multiple occurrences in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have an elastic search data structure like this:

```
{"sender": "ab",
 "receiver": "cd",
 "tag": "case1"}

{"sender": "ef",
 "receiver": "gh",
 "tag": "case1"}

{"sender": "ab",
 "receiver": "ij",
 "tag": "case2"}

{"sender": "vw",
 "receiver": "xy",
 "tag": "case2"}

{"sender": "xy",
 "receiver": "ab",
 "tag": "case3"}

...
```

Now I want to find all senders or receivers that occur in more than one case. For example, if I query for a "cross match" for **case1**, **case2** and **case3**, I should get **ab** as a result, since **ab** was a sender or receiver in documents of all three cases.

Another example: A cross-match-query for **case2** and **case3** should return **ab** and **xy**, since both appeared as senders or receivers in the specified cases.

How would I query this in elasticsearch - or even better directly in kibana?

Comment: I could use term aggregations for the different cases and compare/cross-check those in an external script, but I think this might be possible right inside ES itself. And I would love to create a dashboard-visualisation for this in Kibana as well...

Comment: So you're trying to find a tag if the send and receiver contain the search query?